# How to print linked list in python without None error

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I have a simple linked list I am building and I am able to print it in reverse order (first node added is printed last) but I would like to print it in normal order. However I am not sure why I keep getting an error about not being able to print None.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None
  def addNextData(self, data):
    self.next = Node(data)
    return self.next
  def __str__(self):
    if(self is None):
      return "None"
    print(self.data)
    return print(self.next)

node = Node("a")
node.addNextData("b") \
  .addNextData("c") \
  .addNextData("d")
print(node)
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)`

I have resorted to doing it like this but it print unnecessary blank strings/lines:

```
  def __str__(self):
    if(self is None):
      return "None"
    print(self.data)
    print(self.next)
    return ""
```

I am able to do this iteratively but maybe there is a more elegant way to do it via print/recursive:

```
  def __str__(self):
    head = self
    str = ''
    while(head is not None):
      str = str + head.data  + '->'
      head = head.next
    return str + 'None'
```

I am having a hard time understanding why this (reverse order printing) does not throw the None error. :

```
def __str__(self):
    print(self.next)
    return self.dat
```

Also confused since print(None) doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to print anything from a `__str__` method - it should only return a `str`. `print` is a function that prints a string but doesn't return anything so `return print(...)` is equivalent to `return None`. This is the cause of your `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)` error.

```
if(self is None):
      return "None"
```

Is also a no-op as `self` will never* be `None` as it is (by definition) an instance of your `Node` type.

In your case you could do something like

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None
  def addNextData(self, data):
    self.next = Node(data)
    return self.next
  def __str__(self):
      value = str(self.data)
      n = self.next
      while n is not None:
          value += "->" + str(n.data)
          n = n.next
      return value

node = Node("a")
node.addNextData("b") \
  .addNextData("c") \
  .addNextData("d")
print(node)
```

The `__str__` method could be made recursive instead with something like the following but an iterative approach is generally better than a recursive version that does the same thing.

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.next is not None:
        return str(self.data) + ", " + str(self.next)
    else:
        return str(self.data)
```

* Never unless you intentionally go out of your way to call it directly with `None`, eg(`Node.__str__(None)`)

Comment: Thank you, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this recursively, and leveraging `__str__.` I have a similar solution in my post above for the iterative version.  Shortly after posting I realized print is returning None so thanks for reaffirming that. Still wondering if there is a clean way to do it recursively without the extra blank lines

Comment: What do you mean by recursively and what output are you expecting? This example will already include the full list. I'll add a recursive version but in general an iterative approach is the better option if possible.

Comment: I just wanted to see if it was possible to achieve recursively and it seems the key is in str() which seems to also call __str__ but in a different way than print(). That seems to work and did not know that was possible thanks!